# What's the equivalence of an SQL WHERE in Lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda

Here's what I have:

```
decimal sum = _myDB.Products.Sum(p => p.Price).GetValueOrDefault();
```

I also have two dates: `DateTime start`, `DateTime end`
I want to retrieve the sum of all of the product prices between start and end, but I can't figure out how to incorporate the variables into the lambda equation.

How do you incorporate variables into a lambda equation to give it some specification?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx)

```
decimal sum = _myDB.Products
                   .Where(p => (p.Date >= start) && (p.Date <= end) )
                   .Sum(p => p.Price)
                   .GetValueOrDefault();
```

Comment: Agreed in terms of implementation, but queries like this are a lot clearer on multiple lines. Line up the dots :)

Comment: Good point on the formatting - I just stuck with his original question's formatting method, for consistency, but this is how I typically write it in my own code.

Comment: @Jon: Done. Didn't see your comment until just now.

Comment: Good point Jon. There is always something to learn (even from comments). Haha :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 decimal sum = _myDB.Products
.Where(p => p.Start >= mystartDate && p.End <= myenddate)
.Sum(p => p.Price)
```

Pardon my syntax. But, I hope you get the idea.

EDIT: Corrected after Reed's suggestion.
Old code (incorrect)

```
 decimal sum = _myDB.Products
.Sum(p => p.Price)
.Where(p => p.Start >= mystartDate && p.End <= myenddate)
```

Comment: The Where clause needs to go before Sum.  Sum returns a decimal, and you can't do ".Where" on a decimal value.

Comment: Guys, will this work differently (i.e different from WHERE and then SUM)?

Comment: This won't compile at all.  You cannot run .Where on a single value, which is what's returned by Sum().

Comment: No problem.  When you're using a fluent interface like this, each method returns a new object.  In the case of methods like Where(), it returns a new IEnumerable<T>, which is why you can "chain" them together.  .Sum() just returns a single value (decimal), so you can't do another method that's expecting IEnumerable<T> after Sum()

Answer (score 0):

```
_myDB.Products
.Where(p => p.start >= "somevalue")
.Where(p => p.end <= "somevalue")
.Sum(p => p.Price).GetValueOrDefault();
```

Comment: There's no need to have two where clauses with separate predicates.